# My App got errors in a galaxy tab 8 android 5

Tags: android, google-maps

this my first post, I did an app in eclipse  using google maps api v2. the app works fine in android 4.2.2 y 4.3 but in android 5.0 the app crashed with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
    at com.alezanper.reporter.F_map.MapInit(F_map.java:97)
    at com.alezanper.reporter.F_map.onCreateView(F_map.java:65)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6411)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Providing some code from where the trace is happening would help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your map **is not correctly initialized**. You should debug it with Android Studio by **placing a breakpoint** when you initialize your map to see what happen.

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni It is certainly an *attempt* to answer, because it diagnoses the problem and gives a hint at a solution. If you think that this answer is wrong or not useful, then you can vote on it.

Comment: As @ArtjomB. said, it was a part of an answer. **Null Reference Exception** are always the same thing to debug. I provided the "**How to debug** this" solution.